# Unable to pick up custom camel converter

Tags: apache-camel

I've created a new converter with the following structure:

```
package com.mycompany;

@Converter
public final class MyCustomConverter {
  @Converter
  public static TypeB convert(TypeA typeA) {
  // do the conversion
  }
}
```

I've also created in my `src/main/java/resources` folder the following package, `META-INF.services.org.apache.camel` and within that a `TypeConverter` file which just says:

```
com.mycompany
```

Within my route from `TypeA` I have got:

```
<convertBodyTo type="com.mycompany.TypeB" />
```

Yet my tests constantly fail to pick up the file and thus cannot find the converter, with the exception being:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No
>   type converter available to convert from type: com.mycompany.TypeA to
>   the required type: com.mycompany.TypeB with value TypeA[value1="blah"]

Am I meant to do something else to get my test to pick up the TypeConverter file? Surely putting it in that resources folder with the exact structure adds it to the classpath and so it would be accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its recommended in the TypeConverter file to list the FQN of all the type conveters, eg

```
com.mycompany
```

Should be

```
com.mycompany.MyCustomConverter
```

This is also what we say on this page: http://camel.apache.org/type-converter.html

And could you check inside the generated JAR file of yours, that the META-INF/services/org/apache/camel directory is there, and that the TypeConverter file is present (and it is not in some directory like META-INF/org.apache.camel).

Also what is the runtime environment you use? Do you run Camel standalone, Tomcat, OSGi or something else?

Comment: Thanks Claus. Actually I've found my converter does work. However one of our tests which generally mocks everything out is failing as it cannot locate the converter. I presume there's something in camel-test which allows me to mock out the convertBodyTo call. Thanks for the tip about explicitly naming the converter.

Comment: We're using an OSGI environment, and the test class in question is extending CamelBlueprintTestSupport.

Comment: Can you check if you generate the right META-INF/services/ file rightly in you test bundle?

Comment: @Claus can you guide on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29679141/junit-tests-fails-ramdomly-camel-2-15-1-custom-typeconvertor-not-getting-loade